# Get All Text Elements from Page

Tags: javascript, html, text, element

I am working on a Chrome extension that finds top few font sizes on a page. In order to do so, I need to get all of the text related elements from the page. How can I pull any text related element from the HTML page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple. Use the following code.

```
textInputs = [];
var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
_length = fields.length,
input;
for(var i = 0; i < _length; i++){
    input = fields[i];
    if (!input.type || input.type === 'text'){
            textInputs.push(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully, by "text related" he's referring to input elements; otherwise the loop is over practically every element other than the strictly graphical ones, such as canvas or img... ;)

Comment: He wrote 'fields' in the title and 'elements' in the description. Could the OP please clear this up?

Comment: My bad, I fixed it. I was unaware about the terminology. I intended not the fields, but text related elements like elements <p>, <h1>, or <li>.